# Sticky bit enabled Script can't write to a root file

Tags: setuid, suid, guid

I have 2 files in the /tmp/.

- The first one is an empty file named "file" with permission `-rw-------` and owner `root:root`.
- The second file is named "script" which is a simple Ruby script with permission `-rwsr-xr-x` and owner `root:root`.
  The contents of the script file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$-v = true

IO.write( File.join(Dir.pwd, 'file'), 100.times.map { rand(97..122).chr }.join << ?\n )
```

---

The file "file" has the same permission as the `/etc/shadow` file:

```
# ls -l /etc/shadow
-rw------- 1 root root 1045 Sep 22 04:13 /etc/shadow

# ls -l file
-rw------- 1 root root 6 Nov 29 12:22 file
```

The ruby script "script" has the same permission as the `passwd` command:

```
$ ls -l $(type -p passwd)
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 63624 Nov 13 22:28 /usr/bin/passwd

# ls -l script
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 78 Nov 29 12:22 script
```

I can run `./script` as root which replaces the contents of the file "file" with some random string.

But when I run `./script` as a non-root user, Ruby raises `Errno::EACCES`.

---

Can I write to the the root writeable file "file" as non-root user by correctly setting up the SUID permission?

Comment: you are talking about suid bit. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question

Comment: Suid bit is ignored on scripts (executable files with shebang interpreter).

Comment: If I remove the #! line, then <1> it's not recognized as a Ruby file <2> Running it with Ruby interpreter also raises Errno::EACCES

Comment: I have also tried it with the Crystal programming language. The compiler produces compiled binary. The program writes to file. I can just execute that to write to the file a random string, but I am getting permission error when non-root users are trying to access the file. I am surely doing something wrong? Otherwise how does passwd not raises `Errno::EACCES` (assuming it's in C) when non-root users run it?

Comment: Tutorials like https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/ and the others I have seen teaches how to set sticky bit, but they don't demonstrate the purpose of doing so. They don't test that the files are writeable. So I am seeking the help of serverfault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an Access Control List (ACL) instead. In the command below I (dmo) give the user *bob* read/write access to a file called *test*:

```
$ setfacl -m u:bob:rw test
```

Now `ls` shows a `+` sign at the end of the permissions to indicate that an ACL is in effect on a file.

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 dmo dmo 0 Nov 29 07:22 test
```

To see what the ACL allows use `getfacl`:

```
$ getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: dmo
# group: dmo
user::rw-
user:bob:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

As you can see *bob* now has the write access he needs.

If you want to remove the ACL you can use `setfacl --remove-all`:

```
$ setfacl --remove-all test
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dmo dmo 0 Nov 29 07:22 test
```

There are some good tutorials around on ACL's which are an often overlooked feature: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux

Finally, be very careful of who you allow to write to files owned/read by the *root* user.

Comment: That works. but how do I revert / undo the effect of setfacl command?

Comment: Answer updated to add remove ACL command.

Comment: I am wondering why it is not working (as root) on my second partition with Nil file system mounted on /mnt/ 

Comment: It's possible NILFS does not support ACL? It does say "Basic POSIX file system features" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS. You can try adding -o acl to the mount options.